# Find the vector equation for the line passing through the point P and parallel to the line

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is find the vector equation for the line passing through the point P= (4,7,8) and parallel to the line:
x = 8 + 8t
y = -7 + 8t
z = 6 - 2t

I have a feeling that I should take the distance between the two lines but for example the "t" in the 8 + 8t part is confusing me.

The format is like this:
[0,0,0] + t[0,0,0]

I think part of the answer is:
[4,7,8] but not sure what the t part is

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given line

$$x = 8 + 8t \quad y = -7 + 8t \quad z = 6 - 2t\implies (8,-7,6)+t\cdot (8,8,-2)$$

has direction vector $$v=(8,8,-2)$$

Then the line passing through $P$ and parallel to the given line is

$$P+t\cdot v=(4,7,8)+t\cdot (8,8,-2)$$